# How to write common code for all similar type of beans in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I have multiple types of cars inside my Vehicle class and all the cars are having their respective attributes and getters/setters. I am having the populated Vehicle class object with the values of the requested specific type of car. I wish to get those values and store them in a separate bean in a common manner. Please take a look at the below codebase for more details.

```java
public class Cars {

    private BMW bmw;
    private Hyundai hyundai;
    private TATAMotors tataMotors;
    private Ferrari ferrari;

    // getters and setters

}
```

```java
public class BMW  {

    private String carid;
    private long price;
    private String carName;
    private double tax;

    //getters and setters
}
```

I am having the same type of other beans like for Ferrari, Hyundai, etc.

I wish to write a common code for all types of cars instead of doing `cars.getBMW().getCarId()` or `cars.getFerrari().getCarId()` to store those values to another bean.

I am hitting only one type of car in a single request at runtime. Request can contain any single type of car, and without depending on the car type or car name I just want to execute a common code.

please advise.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, what you are doing goes in the wrong direction when it comes to Object-Oriented Programming.

You are using the class `Cars` as a data container. Java has a lot of data containers that can be used for that purpose, such as `array`, `ArrayList<>`, and so on.

What you could do, is use **inheritance**.

Create a class `Car` or `Vehicle` depending on your use case...

```java
public class Car
{
    // Put all common attributes and functions of a car here!
    private String carId;
    private long price;
    private String carName;
    private double tax;

    public void horn()
    {
        System.out.println("BEEEEP");
    }
}
```

Inherit from the `Car` class.

```java
public class BMW extends Car
{
    // Put specific attributes of BMW here, or if there aren't any, just leave it empty
}
```

Then use the common attributes of the car on each subclass.

```java
BMW bmw = new BMW();
bmw.horn();
```